# systemd: multiple units of the same

Tags: linux, systemd

I try to start multiple processes with systemd - restart if it terminated included. The only difference is the argument of the processes.

Is there a way to avoid a unit-file per process??
I am looking for a unit-file for all processes together.

Normally I would use a start-skript but - as I said - restart in case of termination should be also included. And I do not see a way to do it with pure systemd and no handmade skriptlets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps using a template unit fits your needs. From [systemd.unit(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

> Optionally, units may be instantiated from a template file at runtime. This allows creation of multiple units from a single configuration file. If systemd looks for a unit configuration file, it will first search for the literal unit name in the file system. If that yields no success and the unit name contains an "@" character, systemd will look for a unit template that shares the same name but with the instance string (i.e. the part between the "@" character and the suffix) removed. Example: if a service getty@tty3.service is requested and no file by that name is found, systemd will look for getty@.service and instantiate a service from that configuration file if it is found.
>
> To refer to the instance string from within the configuration file you may use the special "%i" specifier in many of the configuration options. See below for details.

So you might create a file myservice@.service that reads something like

```
[Unit]
Description=MyService component %i
PartOf=myservice.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/myservice %i
Restart=on-failure
```

and the master unit myservice.target as

```
[Unit]
Description=Myservice
Requires=myservice@a.service myservice@b.service myservice@c.service
```

The PartOf= specification in myservice@.service ensures that when the target is stopped or restarted each component is as well. With Requires= in myservice.target each component must be started for myservice to have successfully started. I think it should be the case that if any individual component fails any that didn't fail should be terminated; i.e. its all or nothing. If that's not what you want you might use Want= instead of Requires=.

It's a little awkward, but if you need to supply multiple arguments you can introduce an indirection through environment variables. For the template unit add `Environment=args=%i` and replace `%i` in the ExecStart with `$args`. I think it'd be better to find an alternative to that, but without knowing more about your use-case I'm not sure what that solution would be.

Comment: Please one more question:
how to pass more than 1 argument?

I tried
Requires=myservice@"a 1".service 
but does not work

Comment: @chris maybe the last addition to the answer helps?

Comment: I tried the Environment. It works but only for the actual unit. Can I set in the target the environement for the depencencies (requires, wants)??
I didnt get to manage that.